# How does a large -Xss setting affect server performance?

Tags: java

I have a Java server that reads a large serialised file at startup. This requires a large -Xss setting solely for the main thread at startup. All threads that handle server requests require much less stack space. (Xss is 20M).

How will this (continually increasing) Xss value affect the server's memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is complicated. **You're also asking the wrong question - make sure you read the entire answer all the way to the end**.

### Answering your question: How bad is large `-Xss`?

The amount of RAM a JVM needs is, basically, heap+metaspace+MAX_THREADS*STACK_SIZE.

Heap is simple: That's what the `-Xmx` parameter is for. metaspace is a more or less constant (I'm oversimplifying) and not particularly large amount.

Furthermore, assuming it's the usual server setup where you've set things up such that the JVM gets a static amount of memory (it's a server - it has a set amount of RAM and the best option, usually, is to spend it all. Give every major process running on the system a locked in configured amount of RAM. If the JVM is the only major software running on there (e.g. there is a database involved but it runs on another machine), and you have 8GB in the box, then give the JVM ~7GB. Why wouldn't you? Use `-Xmx` and -Xms`, set to the same value, and make it large. If postgres is also running on it, give the JVM perhaps 3GB and postgres 4GB (depends on how db-heavy your app is, of course). etcetera.

The point is, if you have both a large stacksize and a decently large max threads, let's say an `-Xss` of 20MB and max-threads of 100, then you lose 2GB of your allocated 7: On a box with 8GB installed and only the JVM as major consumer of resources, this setting:

```
java -Xmx7g -Xms7g -Xss20m
```

would be **completely wrong** and cause all sorts of trouble - that adds up to **9 GB**, and I haven't even started accounting for metaspace yet, or the needs of the kernel. The box doesn't have that much! Instead you should be doing perhaps `-Xmx5g -Xms5g -Xss20m`.

And now you know what the performance cost is of this: The cost is having to reduce your `-Xmx -Xms` value from 7 to 5. It gets disastrously worse if you had to knock it down from 3 to 1 because it's a 4GB box - at that point what you're doing is basically impossible unless you first launch a new server with more ram in it.

### Actually helping you solve your problem

Forget about all of the above, that's the wrong way to solve this problem. Keep your `-Xss` nice and low, or don't set it.

Instead, take your init code and isolate it, then run it in a separately set up thread (and then just `.join()` on that thread to wait for it to complete and flush all the fields your init code modified back; yield() sets up HB/HA as needed). Use this thread constructor:

```
Runnable initCode = () -> {
   // your init stuff goes here
};

ThreadGroup tg = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
Thread initThread = new Thread(tg, runnable, "init", 20L * 1024L * 1024L);
initThread.start();
initThread.join();
```

But, do some research first. The API of Thread is horribly designed and makes all sorts of grave errors. In particular, the stack size number (20MB here) is **just a hint** and the javadoc says any VM is free to just completely ignore it. Good API design would have of course specced that an exception is thrown instead if your requested stacksize is not doable by the VM.

I've done a quick test; adoptopenjdk 11 on a mac seems to have no problem with it.

Here's my test setup:

```
> cat Test.java
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                Runnable r = () -> {
                        System.out.println("Allowed stack depth: " + measure());
                };
                r.run();
                r.run();
                Thread t = new Thread(Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup(), r, "init", 1024L * 1024L);
                t.start();
                t.join();
                r.run();
        }

        public static int measure() {
                int min = 1;
                int max = 50000;
                while (min < max) {
                        int mid = (max + min) / 2;
                        try {
                                attempt(mid);
                                if (min == mid) return min;
                                min = mid;
                        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
                                max = mid;
                        }
                }
                return min;
        }

        public static void attempt(int depth) {
                if (depth == 0) return;
                attempt(depth - 1);
        }
}

> javac Test.java; java -Xss200k Test
Allowed stack depth: 2733
Allowed stack depth: 6549
Allowed stack depth: 49999
Allowed stack depth: 6549
```

You can't check the size of the stack trace, as the JVM has a hard limit and won't store more than 1024 stack trace elements, thus the binary search for the answer.

I can't quite explain why the value isn't constant (it hops from 2733 to 6549), or even why an `-Xss` of 150k produces *higher* numbers for a real What The Heck???? - I'll ask a question about that right after posting this answer, but it does show that the thread that was made with a larger stack does indeed let you have a far deeper method callstack.

Run this test code on the target environment with the target JDK just to be sure it'll work, and then you have your actual solution :)

Comment: Thank you. The Thread constuctor with a stack size was exactly what I was missing.

Comment: Are you sure of "MAX_THREADS*STACK_SIZE"? testing it with a -xss=1G does not make a process with such a massive memory consumption. To the best of my knowledge the Java stack memory is dynamically allocated.

Comment: @MarcoServetto invalid stack sizes are silently ignored (as if you didn't specify an `-Xss` param in the first place), and a _lot_ of values are considered invalid (for example, anything that isn't an exact multiple of some unknown boundary window size is considered invalid, e.g. `900k` is not going to work on just about all JVMs). Yes, I am sure. Presumably, 1G is not valid.

Comment: This is confusing. If from the command line I start the JVM with -xss1G or with1024M I get the same result (on linux)
If I start it with 1025M I get a clear error telling that it is too much. So...

Comment: As I highlighted in the answer, it's pirate law. `-Xss` is more what you'd call guidelines than actual rules. I don't know why you are observing what you are observing; the JVM doing some fancypants dynamically allocated stack-per-thread is news to me. My code above may help fill the stack; run with `-Xss1g`, run my snippet (without the separate thread, just the 'depth measurer' part) and see if you can actually pile a gig's worth on there. Should be __millions__ instead of the tens-of-thousands I'm getting, if you really have a 1G stack. Very interesting!